# Windows;Powershell - Determine when Service Control Manager fires up from a reboot

Tags: windows, powershell

Powershell cmdlet Write-Host partnered w/ Test-Connection cmdlet in a Do/Until loop to output lines of when a server machine is shut down and NIC re-initializes. Once Service Control Manager fires up after reboot, I want to then restart a computer service.

How exactly can I know when SCM is up and happy as I'm currently trying to restart computer service just after the NIC initializes to start replying to ICMP ping which SCM is not alive yet thus craps out on Restart-Service cmdlet?

Comment: It will be good if you can share your current code here.

Comment: I'd rather not as I see a lot of folks from viewing this site picking out irrelevant sections. I feel like my question is point blank.

Comment: A machine is coming up from a reboot. How can one tell when SCM is alive and ready to handle a Restart-Service PS cmdlet. That is as straight forward as it comes

Comment: I suggest reading [ask] (specifically the section on [mcve]) as your question is likely to be closed as it has no code. Just listing some commands `Write-Host/Test-Connection/Do/Until` isn't any help to us without knowing how they're being used.

Comment: Good call out James. I am reading this on now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are initiating reboot using `Restart-Computer` you can use the `-Wait` with `-For winrm` , that means , once the winrm service is up, `Restart-computer` cmdlet will complete its execution.

`Get-Help Restart-Computer -online`

Comment: After some late night digging the cmdlet Start-Sleep is what I was hunting. Just a way to restart a computer service prior to the OS (SCM component) being completely loaded up was hindering me.